# How do I replace characters enclosed inside of two brackets in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

In Notepad++, how can I replace a certain character (`.`) that is enclosed within two brackets `[]` throughout a large file?

#### Explanation

I have a very long code dump file (of PeopleCode) in Notepad++. At the top of each section of code, there is a tag like this:

```
[G3FORM.FormFactory.OnExecute]
```

This denotes a class package, and a class. In addition, this can be multiple layers deep:

```
[Y_REST.RESTQueries.ExampleClass.OnExecute]
```

Whenever a class is declared in the code, it doesn't use `.`'s. It uses `:`'s. E.g.:

```
import G3FORM:Form;
```

So, when I want to search for that class in the code dump, I have to change all of the `.`'s into `:`. I can do that, but it's somewhat annoying.

#### Example

I would like some help with Notepad++'s regex search feature for find and replace. I need to replace all of the `.`'s contained within these headers with `:`'s. E.g.:

```
[Y_REST.RESTQueries.ExampleClass.OnExecute]
```

would become

```
[Y_REST:RESTQueries:ExampleClass.OnExecute]
```

All but the last colon are replaced (and even then, if that makes it overly complicated, the last `.` can also be replaced).

#### Failed Attempts

I have been playing around with some regex to try and get this, but I am not familiar enough with it.

This doesn't work at all:

```
(([A-Z])\.)+
```

This also doesn't find anything:

```
\[(([A-Z])\.)+\]
```

I'm probably way off base. I haven't used regex enough to be familiar enough to know how to use the find and replace with regex.

Comment: If it's not nested, just use the `\G` anchor.

Comment: You can use `(?:\[[^\]\[.]*|(?!^)\G)[^\]\[.]*\K\.(?![^\]\[.]*\])(?=[^\]\[]*\])`, to replace with a `:`.

Comment: Well, one character class is redundant: `(?:\[|(?!^)\G)[^\]\[.]*\K\.(?![^\]\[.]*\])(?=[^\]\[]*\])`

Answer (score 0):

Do a regular expression find/replace like this:

- Open Replace Dialog
- **Find What:** `(\[[^\].]+)\.([^\]]+\])`
- **Replace With:** `\1:\2`
- check **regular expression**
- click Replace or Replace All
- Keep Alt-A (Replace All) pressed until the message in find dialogs status bar tells you "0 occurences were replaced"

Comment: What does the `\1:\2` do?

Comment: Also, doesn't seem to catch multiple `.`'s as in the case of `[Y_DCE_FUNCLIB:DCE_Email.BATCH_EMAIL_MANAGERS.EFYFilterRejectedBatchEmail.OnExecute]`

Comment: @CacheStaheli *ReplaceAll* replaces *one* "." in *all* lines. Thus you have to keep Alt-A pressed to replace until all replacements are done. 

For a basic introduction to Regular expression, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075 . 

The `\1` and `\2` are backreferences that are filled from the *Find What *part with the actual text matched by the first and second parentheses. pair.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `(?:(?!\A)\G|\[(?=[^\[\]]+\]))[^\[\].]*\K\.`

Explanation

```
 (?:                           # Cluster start
      (?! \A )                      # Not beginning of string
      \G                            # G anchor - If matched before, start at end of last match
   |                              # or
      \[                            # Open bracket
      (?= [^\[\]]+ \] )             # Only if there is a closing bracked down stream
 )                             # Cluster end
 [^\[\].]*                     # Not brackets nor dot
 \K                            # Exclude previous in match
 \.                            # The dot, all thats left
```

Replace with whatever you want.
Note - for performance reasons, we limit latency by checking for closing
bracket only once per open bracket `\[ (?= [^\[\]]+ \] )`

Answer (score 0):

Since the number of levels is limited, one really straightforward approach is to use several searches, one for each number of levels.

Here is a search/replace for four levels:

```
Find what :   \[([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.([^\]]+)\]
Replace with: \[$1:$2:$3:$4\]
```

Search expression is composed of `([^.]+)\.` "not dots followed by a dot" groups enclosed in square brackets.

`$1`..`$4` mean *capturing groups*, i.e. what's matched by the expression in parentheses.

To perform the replacement for fewer or more levels, add remove or add `\.([^\.]+)` in the search box, and adjust the replace box accordingly.